# Servicemix does not find javax.validation bundle

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I'm using servicemix-4.4.1,

Inside my pom.xml I've defined a dependency as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

As you can see I've set the scope to provided because servicemix (the osgi container) will provide the jar(s) for us.

Inside my features.xml file I've added:

```
<feature name="myapp-libs" version="${version}">
    ....
    <bundle>mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.3.1.Final/jar</bundle>
```

Now when I'm trying to load in myapp-libs into servicemix I get the following:

```
karaf@root> features:install myapp-libs
Error executing command: Could not start bundle mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.3.1.Final/jar in feature(s) 
myapp-libs-1.24-SNAPSHOT: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.hibernate.validator [973]: 
Unable to resolve 973.0: missing requirement [973.0] package; (&(package=javax.validation)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have javax.validation defined in my features.xml as such:

```
<bundle>mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/jar</bundle>
```

But then it doesn't find the hibernate-validator jar anymore:

```
Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found. Add a provider like Hibernate Validator (RI) to your classpath.
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:271)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
```

This is strange since in the logs I can see that hibernate-validator is being loaded.

```
22:53:40,835 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                               

    ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:com.googlecode.guava-osgi/guava-osgi/9.0.0/jar
22:53:42,064 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6
22:53:42,203 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle wrap:mvn:junit/junit/4.11/jar
22:53:42,312 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle wrap:mvn:org.apache.thrift/libthrift/0.7.0/jar
22:53:42,441 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle wrap:mvn:org.apache.cassandra/cassandra-thrift/1.1.0/jar
22:53:42,625 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:org.hectorclient/hector-core/1.1-2/jar
22:53:42,836 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.6/jar
22:53:43,396 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.6/jar
22:53:44,396 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.6/jar
22:53:44,416 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.1.0.Final/jar
22:53:44,425 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/jar
22:53:44,459 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-jackson/2.8.0/jar
22:53:44,467 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle mvn:joda-time/joda-time/1.6
22:53:44,780 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle wrap:mvn:org.perf4j/perf4j/0.9.16/jar
22:53:45,061 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle wrap:mvn:org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.6.1/jar
22:53:46,600 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle wrap:mvn:org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.6.1/jar
22:53:46,867 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle wrap:mvn:commons-jexl/commons-jexl/1.1/jar
22:53:46,893 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Installing bundle wrap:mvn:com.eaio.uuid/uuid/3.2/jar
22:53:46,899 | INFO  | l Console Thread | FeaturesServiceImpl              | ?                                   ? | 30 - org.apache.karaf.features.core - 2.2.2.fuse-07-11 | Bundles to refresh:
```

Comment: You most likely need to configure the ValidationConfiguration being built by buildDefaultValidatorFactory, because it is looking in the bundles local classpath rather than looking through OSGI. In OSGI, there is classpath isolation which means two separate bundles will not be able to find eachother using the traditional means.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.3/reference/en-US/html/validator-bootstrapping.html#section-validation-provider-resolver

Comment: Also you probably want to update the original post rather than adding a comment.

Answer (score 0):

hibernate-validator requires the javax.validation package of versions 1.0.0 or greater, but NOT 2.0.0. That means you need to include another bundle within your features xml OR make sure servicemix is setup with JSR303 / javax.validation support.